# Question about series as infinite summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have two questions about the series.

1. Grandi's series $1-1+1-1+ \cdots$ is not convergent since its partial summation is not convergent. But someone told me it could be convergent if we rearrange the series.
   For example, $1-1+1-1+1-1+...=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+...=0+0+0+...=0$. (1)

> My question is for this new series, we still need to calculate its partial summation by definition and obviously, the partial summation is $S_n=1$ for odds and $S_n=0$ for even, how can we say it is now $lim S_n=0$.

2. About the definition of a series. Do we still regard series as infinite summation($\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=a_1+a_2+...$) even have defined it as the limit of partial summation? And we have $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ for convergent series? And we allow add in parentheses like in (1)?

Comment: You might find helpful info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The rearranging is supposed to trick your intuition to think that we are just adding zeroes, and so it must be $0$ in the limit. More mathematically, it tries to argue that the series is equivalent to the series of the partial sums $S^*_n=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i$, with $u_i = 1-1 = 0$, so $S^*_n = 0$. But as you noted yourself, they are not equal. It *does* identify a convergent subsequence though, $(S_{2n})_n$.
2. The definition is in fact the opposite direction. Infinite summation is not a priori defined, so we define it as the limit of the partial sums, i.e. the series. But the series, when convergent, does have some of the properties you would have for finite summation. E.g. the addition formula you described is an easy exercise for convergent series. Also, parenthesis is allowed, but rearranging might cause problems, see David's link.

Comment: Could you help me understand rearranging, and what it means in series (I've searched a lot and do not find the definition for it. ). Why can we arrange the series (the arrangement is somewhat dealing with infinite elements which is really counter-intuitive)?

Comment: I found some statements saying rearrangement is to build a bijection.  If so, can you tell me how to build the bijection in (1) (the first example in my question)?

Comment: @Andrew what I mean, and what the link in David's comment means, by rearranging is a permutation of the elements of the sequence, thus possibly changing the partial sums. This is indeed a bijection from the set of sequence elements to itself. Grouping elements, as I did in 1., is not a bijection, however.

Comment: Ok, So grouping is like association and rearrangement is like commutation? Any definition for grouping?

Comment: You should seek to become familiar with three types of series: divergent, conditionally convergent and absolutely convergent. For a divergent series, such as the one in 1., not much meaningful can be said about it. It basically means that for the given sequence, it is non-sensical to talk about infinite summation.
However, if the series is convergent, more can be said. Either it is absolutely convergent, i.e. the series of absolute values of the sequence elements converge, or it does not, and we say it is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Absolutely convergent series have basically all the properties we could wish infinite summation to have. This is all standard basic analysis. 
Conditionally convergent series do not, however. For example, their limit may change when the sequence is permuted, again see David's link. This is completely opposite finite summation, where $a+b=b+a$ always when doing standard analysis.